# Where to store values to get them from template in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question about storing values correctly in angular 1. Since $scope is going to be removed in angular2, I want to avoid using it as much as possible and prepare myself for next generation of angular

To show an example, I have some HTML:

```
<span ng-click="axArgicSearch.replace(part.euroCode)"
  class="btn btn-xs btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
></span>
```

and the function for it is:

```
replace: function(partId) {
   return api.glass.selectParts(partId, caseManager.data.id);
}
```

What I want is to change the class of that span if a button is clicked.

Possible way with scope:

```
    <span ng-click="axArgicSearch.replace(part.euroCode)" 
     ng-class={ 'btn btn-xs btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-refresh': $scope.part.euroCode.isSelected, 
    'other-class': !$scope.part.euroCode.isSelected  }">
    ></span>
```

and then is function should be something like:

```
replace: function(partId) {
  $scope.partId.isSelected = true;
  return api.glass.selectParts(partId, caseManager.data.id);
}
```

This is just an exampl--I didn't test it to see if it works.

How would I do something like this without $scope?

Comment: some `function() { var me = this; me.yourValue = theValue; }` - how about this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2.0 is using `this` instead of `$scope`.

Also, using `controller as` may be the solution for your problem in AngularJS 2.0